# Azure Web App with Flask, Gunicorn, Docker running into problems on deployment

Tags: azure, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am working on a backend Flask server that uses gunicorn and Docker for container registry, and I was able to deploy to Azure using docker fine previously. Now I am running into the same problem each time I deploy, getting an error from Azure.

Error logs:

```
2023-04-17T23:55:26.496Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:4d47390fe03a168e908be64364d5fbe92673beeaccbd1d7db726dbd34ed46494
2023-04-17T23:55:26.571Z INFO  -  Status: Downloaded newer image for <name>/flask:latest
2023-04-17T23:55:26.576Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 14 Seconds
2023-04-17T23:55:26.633Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2023-04-17T23:55:26.635Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8000 --name tutor-ag-flaskserver_0_24cc58c0 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITES_PORT=8000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=tutor-ag-flaskserver -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=tutor-ag-flaskserver.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=6f2978b61f339eeffd2de0fbd1035abfc785be48acaa2538361e33d044856829 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e NODE_OPTIONS=--require /agents/node/build/src/Loader.js -e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar -e StartupBootstrapper=Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StartupBootstrapper -e DOTNET_SHARED_STORE=/agents/core/store/lin -e DOTNET_ADDITIONAL_DEPS=/agents/core/additionalDeps -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False <name>/flask:latest
2023-04-17T23:55:31.912Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container tutor-ag-flaskserver_0_24cc58c0 for site tutor-ag-flaskserver
2023-04-17T23:55:32.328Z ERROR - Container tutor-ag-flaskserver_0_24cc58c0 for site tutor-ag-flaskserver is not running, failing site start
2023-04-17T23:55:32.345Z ERROR - Container tutor-ag-flaskserver_0_24cc58c0 didnt respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2023-04-17T23:55:32.354Z INFO  - Stopping site tutor-ag-flaskserver because it failed during startup.
/home/LogFiles/2023_04_18_lw1sdlwk0000MN_default_docker.log  (https://tutor-ag-flaskserver.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_04_18_lw1sdlwk0000MN_default_docker.log)
2023-04-18T03:17:18.128375584Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-04-18T03:17:18.128379284Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-04-18T03:17:18.128396484Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
2023-04-18T03:17:18.128400584Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
2023-04-18T03:17:18.128404084Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-04-18T03:17:18.128407584Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
2023-04-18T03:17:18.128410984Z [2023-04-18 03:17:18 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-04-18T03:17:18.897868188Z [2023-04-18 03:17:18 +0000] [6] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2023-04-18T03:17:18.898279291Z [2023-04-18 03:17:18 +0000] [6] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zT95.png)

It runs fine locally, but for some reason, Azure can't load the app.py file which is inside a subdirectory called 'src'. I have been bashing my head into a wall trying to figure this out, so any help is appreciated.

I have tried creating a new, barebones project without any dependencies and deploying, but I get the same error. I have also tried messing around with the Dockerfile to no avail. I have tried moving the content from all other .py files into the app.py file.